# Position fixed para versão desktop e position relative para versão mobile, como fazer em CSS?

Tags: css, mobile, layout-responsivo

sei que deve ser simples, mas estou garrado aqui nisso, eu tenho uma div com ID chamado Login e tenho que deixar ela como fixed quando a navegação for feita de computadores, portanto na versão mobile essa div terá que ficar como relative, alguém pode exemplificar como fazer isso?

Aqui meu CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .informacoes, .footer-info {
        display: none;
    }

    .login {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 25%;
    }
}


.login {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 7%;
    z-index: 9;
    background: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.80);
    padding: 30px 30px 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    transition: left 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Cara uma boa prática é sempre colocar os @media por último, já depois de todo o CSS. Não sei se vai resolver... Se não resolver vou pedir pra vc editar novamente e colocar o seu HTML inclusive com a head da página e o CSS completo.  Tente também comocar essa teg dentro da head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` pode ser que resolva...

Comment: Quanto aos meta name estão todos inseridos corretamente, mas vou colocar o código depois de todo o CSS pra ver

Comment: @hugocsl velho, perfeito, foi so colocar o media no fim após todo o CSS normal dai funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado... coloca essa consideração na sua resposta, que irei aceita-la após vc colocar essa observação ai do seu comentário

Comment: Ok vou editar minha resposta. e explicar o que aconteceu. Agradeço :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Pelo código que vc postou na pergunta percebe-se que as regras do Media Query estão vindo antes do que seria o `css default`. Com isso está havendo uma sobreposição de classes. O CSS é lido pelo browser de cima para baixo, então quando ele faz a leitura tudo que vem abaixo sobrescreve o que está acima entende. Por isso as regras do @media sempre deve vir ao final do arquivo .css

---

Vc tem que usar os `@media` para construir suas regras CSS, no caso desse exemplo declarei que quando a tela tiver até um máximo de `768px` de largura a `div` tem uma cor e um `position`, quando for maior que `768px` vai ter outra cor e outro `position`.

```css
#login {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #login {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eligendi, quisquam!</span>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Aqui tem uma documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Comment: Então eu já fiz dessa forma mais tá dando errado, vou colocar meu código ai na pergunta, veja lá!